# Ajax status is `success` but callback doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm sending an Ajax request with `$.post`. The server side `PHP` is correct.but callback and `PHP` doesn't work!!

Ajax request:

```
$("#exit").click(function(){
        swal({
             title: "exit",
             text: "Are you sure???",
             type: "info",
             animation: "slide-from-top",
             confirmButtonText:"Yes",
             cancelButtonText: "No",
             showCancelButton: true,
             closeOnConfirm: false,
             showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            },
            function(){
                $.post("send.php",{method:'del',id:$("#hidden").val(),answerer:$("#hidden3").val()},function(data){
                alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

And PHP:

```
 if($method==='del'){
        $qs_id=htmlentities($_POST['id']);
        $answerer=htmlentities($_POT['answerer']);
        include('config.php');
        $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;",$username,$password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $DeleteQs=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM qs WHERE id=:id");
        $DeleteQs->bindParam(':id',$qs_id);
        $DeleteQs->execute();
        $DeleteAnswer=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM ans WHERE q_id=:id");
        $DeleteAnswer->bindParam(':id',$qs_id);
        $DeleteAnswer->execute();
        $ChangeStatus=$conn->prepare("UPDATE register SET wanted=0 WHERE name=:answerer");  
        $ChangeStatus->bindParam(':answerer',$answerer);        
        $ChangeStatus->execute();
        echo "Deleted";

    }
```

I think I should say that I'm getting the `alert()` but it isn't included the `PHP` message.
I'm not receiving any error!

Excuse me if my question is silly:(

Comment: Have you checked your networks tab to see that the file is actually called? Also if the PHP ran into any errors?

Comment: Put echo outside of `if`. And i suppose `$method = $_POST['method']`? Yet i dont this piece of code in ur code. Also, your `===` comparing might fail for some reason

Comment: @Darren Yes,the `transferred` is `ـــــ` and the `size`  is `0`. But I'm not receiving any error either in `PHP` nor `Ajax`

Comment: @lolbas when I put the `echo` outside of `if`,I received the `alert('deleted')`.So I think my `===` comparing has failed but how and why?

Comment: `===` is a full type comparison, what you want is value comparison - `==` as @lolbas stated

Comment: @Darren I wanna a full type comparison!!by the way I tested `==` but it failed:((

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) about type comparisons.

Comment: @Darren thanks but my problem is not the type of the comparison because it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this issue might happen in jQuery at V1.8 and above, maybe this syntax will do:

```
$.post("send.php",{method:'del',id:$("#hidden").val(),answerer:$("#hidden3").val()})
.done(function(response){
    alert(response)
})
.fail(function(response){
    alert("Failed:"+response);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but failed!!I'm using JQ 1.6.3!

Comment: still failed!I'm getting neither `.done()` nor `.fail()` :((

Comment: are you sure you are calling the $.post? :S